# How to Stop In Azure Ad Authentication Sign Out ask for Which account do you want to sign out of?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

In my application i have used `AzureAd` Authentication and that works fine.
but when i signout my application from `AzureAd` Authentication, every time Microsoft redirect url ask for

> Which account do you want to sign out of?

SignOut method is

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

when `SignOut` is execute application is redirect to 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri..... this logout url.

but it ask for which account you want to sign out of? also i am only login with only one account still same ask for which account to sign out of?

like below

[image]

my question is how to sign out from azure ad without asking which account to sign out of?

is this Microsoft inbuilt redirect url or any property require to set to stop this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible today to avoid the option to choose the account, on the v2 endpoint's logout URL.

One likely reason is that in [Section 5. RP-initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout) of the [OpenID Connect Session Management](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) spec, we find the following:

> At the logout endpoint, the OP SHOULD ask the End-User whether he wants to log out of the OP as well. If the End-User says "yes", then the OP MUST log out the End-User.

One of the things that this helps avoid is a malicious app or site triggering a logout unbeknownst to the user, which would be a form of denial of service.

Comment: So does that mean the version 1 logout URL works?  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout

Comment: I've tested the v1 endpoint and it works as expected. It's been confirmed that the v2 endpoint doesn't support this behavior: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/126

Comment: as you mentioned in V2 enpoints it is not possible then can you help for how can i do this what is the solution for this problem.

Comment: i am login with only 1 azure account then still showing same when we go for logout, if we have multiple account and then it is fine to show sign-out of which account

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to this [Azure Sample: Signing out](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-6-SignOut).
There seems to be support in ASP NET Core for a new event to handle that situation you described. For the ASP.NET 4.x full framework I could not find a similar event, but as you tagged NET Core, please have a look!